# how to reformat subreport links while exporting to excel in crystal report

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report rpt which with a subreport

below is the current format of the report
[image]

below the preferred format of the report while exporting to the excel data format.
[image]

How can we achive this with out creating a new rpt

Comment: Are you using the designer to export ? It's often not reliable depending on your configuration. Make sure the labels ( client, date, start time...) are on Report Header and that they are right next to eachother like this [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/2FT2CdQ)

Comment: Do you export to excel programatically? I mean, do you know that the report is supposed to be exported to excel before he is generated?

Comment: We actually export the same rpt into excel, pdf, word etc using crystal report. My report consists of a primary report and a subreport.  the subreport is where all the task details are shown in the first screen short and primary report is where the client information is stored. the primary report is linked with subreport using the client id.

Comment: i need to list the details like there is no subreport? is there anyway we can do this in crystal report with out creating a new rpt?